# Poetry clears all [metadata.files] during "add" command

Tags: python-poetry

I already have poetry.lock file, which contains [metadata.files] section filled with packages, files and hashes:

```
[metadata.files]
amqp = [
    {file = "amqp-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:6f0956d2c23d8fa6e7691934d8c3930eadb44972cbbd1a7ae3a520f735d43359"},
    {file = "amqp-5.1.1.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:2c1b13fecc0893e946c65cbd5f36427861cffa4ea2201d8f6fca22e2a373b5e2"},
]
anyascii = [
    {file = "anyascii-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:8707d3185017435933360462a65e2c70a4818490745804f38a5ca55e59eb56a0"},
    {file = "anyascii-0.3.1.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:dedf57728206e286c91eed7c759505a5e45c8cd01367dd40c2f7248bb15c11f6"},
]
...
```

Whe I add a dependency:

```
poetry add Unidecode@^1.3.4
```

a package is installed, lock file is written.
But the section becomes "cleared":

```
[metadata.files]
amqp = []
anyascii = []
...an so on
```

Is that OK?

Comment: Looks like it is [this issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5970). This is not OK. You should update Poetry.